# XPath query : Get specific value with condition

Tags: xml, xpath

I make a JAVA program to parse xml file like this exemple :

```
<lom:contribute>
        <lom:role>
            <lom:source>LOMv1.0</lom:source>
            <lom:value>author</lom:value>
        </lom:role>
        <lom:entity>toto</lom:entity>
        <lom:date>
            <lom:dateTime>2009-10-07</lom:dateTime>
        </lom:date>
    </lom:contribute>
    <lom:contribute>
        <lom:role>
            <lom:source>LOMv1.0</lom:source>
            <lom:value>instructional designer</lom:value>
        </lom:role>
        <lom:entity>titi</lom:entity>
        <lom:date>
            <lom:dateTime>2009-10-07</lom:dateTime>
        </lom:date>
    </lom:contribute>
```

I would like to make XPath query to get the entity (toto in this exemple) when the role value is author. I have make this query for the moment : `//*[local-name()='contribute']/*[local-name()='role']/*[local-name()='value'] = 'author'`. This query return true if author was present in file but I don't know how to get entity value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't your XML lacking a root node? (and the namespace declaration)

Comment: I have a root node in my document, it's a little part of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath returns `toto`:

```
//*[local-name()='contribute'][*[local-name()='role']/*[local-name()='value'] = 'author']/*[local-name()='entity']/text()
```

If you remove the last `/text()`, it returns the `entity` element containing the text `toto`. I'm not sure which of them are you looking for.

Comment: @Mattasse Glad to help. By the way, I'm not sure about Java, but in C# you can specify the XPath namespaces by using some framework classes. If that's possible in Java, you could get rid of those `local-name() = 'something'` calls and make the XPath way shorter (and probably more robust)

Comment: Thanks for advice but it's for a school project.. So I have to make this in Java.

Comment: @Mattasse I was not suggesting to change the programming language, but suggesting to look for something in Java equivalent to the .Net Framework class. Unfortunately I'm not Java expert, so I don't know if such thing exists. You could ask in StackOverflow about that... or maybe just let the XPath as it is right now :)